# Why is Thread.MemoryBarrier used here?

Tags: c#, thread-safety

Browsing through the MEF source code I found this piece.
Can somebody explain why `MemoryBarrier` is needed inside a lock?

The whole method is:

```
public void SatisfyImportsOnce(ComposablePart part)
{
    this.ThrowIfDisposed();

    if (this._importEngine == null)
    {
        ImportEngine importEngine = new ImportEngine(this, this._compositionOptions);

        lock(this._lock)
        {
            if (this._importEngine == null)
            {
                Thread.MemoryBarrier();
                this._importEngine = importEngine;
                importEngine = null;
            }
        }
        if(importEngine != null)
        {
            importEngine.Dispose();
        }
    }
    this._importEngine.SatisfyImportsOnce(part);
}
```

Comment: It *seems* that sometimes, the lock is not enough

Comment: It's impossible to answer this question without knowing a lot more context.

Comment: It is FUD on a processor with a weak memory model, some Microsoft programmers will probably never recover from having to tame the Itanium.  It ensures that another thread can observe the fully constructed object when it uses the _importEngine reference.  On a weak processor that reference could be written to memory before the object fields are written so another thread could see the uninitialized field value.  Not necessary since .NET 2.0 and definitely not necessary here since the lock already implies a memory barrier.

Comment: This should be replaceable with Lazy or LazyInitializer.

Answer (score 1):

[Thread.MemoryBarrier](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.threading.thread.memorybarrier(v=vs.110).aspx) prevents jitter/compiler any instructions reordering for code optimization.

In [Treading in C#, by Joe Albahari](http://www.albahari.com/threading/part4.aspx#_Memory_Barriers_and_Volatility) book he sais:

- The compiler, CLR, or CPU may reorder your program's instructions to improve efficiency.
- The compiler, CLR, or CPU may introduce caching optimizations such that assignments to variables won't be visible to other threads right away.

In this example it might be that importEngine or _importEngine values are cached and it is very important that all threads has to be notified about changes right away.

Also MemoryBarrier in this case provides importEngine *freshness* garantee before it assigned to _importEngine

Comment: But the lock also implies a memory barrior. Neither `importEngine` nor `_importEngine` could be cached inside the lock. (unless other stuff writes to `_importEngine` without locking on `this._lock`).

Comment: @ScottChamberlain you are correct. And that is why I think MemoryBarrier is used in this case, there might be the other threads that writes to _importEnginge without using _lock.

Comment: In the CLI (the standardized version of the CLR) the basic null checks on the double checked locking idiom are insufficent. The CLI's memory model would require the variable to be volatile, or the use of an explicit barrier. The CLR has a stronger memory model, and neither volatile nor a barrier is needed. The authors of that code might not have been aware of the extra guarantee of the CLR, or like Jon Skeet prefers not to rely on them. The barrier has limited cost, since once initialized and synchronized, later calls will skip the content of the lock entirely.

Comment: The main references are an [msdn magazine article](https://web.archive.org/web/20150326171404/https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/magazine/cc163715.aspx) and [a post on cbrumm's blog](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/cbrumme/archive/2003/05/17/51445.aspx).